# adb reverse --list on Android 5

Tags: android, adb

The following scenario:

- Windows 10 machine with adb version 1.0.40
- rooted Android phones, anything from android 5 to 8

An application does the following on each found adb device:

- a reverse connection is set up on each phone using `adb -s xxx reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080`
- using `adb -s xxx reverse --list` is checked if the reverse is set up correctly
- The android application opens a WebSocket connection to a running WS server on the PC

On Android 6 and higher, the --list command returns `(reverse) tcp:8080 tcp:8080`, which is correct. The android application opens the WebSocket connection properly.

Problem:
On any Android 5 phone, the following happens:

- opening the reverse works properly.
- Android is opening the WS connection to the PC
- **The command `adb -s xxx reverse --list` is returning the error `error: protocol fault (couldn't read status length): No error`**
- This causes the phone to be disconnected and reconnected again (seeing the windows popup of the connected device)
- This, of course, also kills the WebSocket connection

Now my questions:

- I couldn't find the above error message, even with googling.
  Shouldn't it at least appear somewhere in some Adb source code?
- Is there any component which does the Adb stuff on Android, that
  could be updated somehow, or is it tied to the android version?
- Could this check (adb reverse --list) also done on the adb shell?
- Any other ideas how to do the check without that command or make the
  command work on Android 5?